# infer generic parameter of the return type based on the resolved value of a type inside the function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to infer the generic parameter of the return type based on the resolved value of a type inside the function.

Given:

```
export type Context = any;
export type Handler<T> = (ctx: Context) => Promise<T>;
export type Middleware<T> = (ctx: Context, handler: Handler<T>) => Promise<T>;

export function compose<T>(...middlewares: Middleware<unknown>[]): Middleware<T> {
  return async function compositeMiddleware(
    ctx: Context, 
    handler: Handler<T> // <-- I want T to be what is resolved here
  ): Promise<T> {
    // ...
  };
}
```

with the return type of `compose` that is `Middleware<T>`, I want `T` to become whatever `Handler<T>`'s `T` resolves to (see the second parameter of `compositeMiddleware`)

So that when I use it like this

```
const middleware1: Middleware = async (ctx, next) => {
  console.log('Middleware 1 Before');
  const result = await next(ctx);
  console.log('Middleware 1 After');
  return result;
};

const middleware2: Middleware = async (ctx: Context, next: Handler<unknown>) => {
  console.log('Middleware 2 Before');
  const result = await next(ctx);
  console.log('Middleware 2 After');
  return result;
};

const compositeMiddleware = compose(middleware1, middleware2);

const result = await compositeMiddleware({}, async () => {
  return {
    id: 'mock-id',
  };
});

result.id
```

I want the return type of `compositeMiddleware` (i.e. `const result`) to be return type of `async () => ...`.

Currently, `result.id` errors with `Property 'id' does not exist on type 'unknown'.`

I do not want to have to explicitly specify the type via `const result: MyType` or `compose<MyType>`.

Is what I am trying to do even possible? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] that demonstrates the issue when we copy and paste it into our own IDEs.  Right now `middleware1` and `middleware2` are undeclared, as is `ctx`.  Also some test cases that show inputs and desired output types will be useful, or maybe you can implement the function fully?  I really don't know what relationship the `middlewares` parameter has with the desired output (and if there's no relationship, maybe you shouldn't have that parameter at all?) If you make it easier for us to get started and test solutions, it will be more likely you'll get a useful answer.

Comment: Sorry, you've got things annotated as `Middleware` without a generic type argument, which yields errors.  Can you try your example code out in an IDE (like the TS Playground) to make sure that the only issues are the ones you're asking about?  (and please include the code as plaintext)

Comment: (see prev comment) I mean, *maybe* you want [this](https://tsplay.dev/N9V5Jm), but as I said at the beginning, I don't understand why `middlewares` is even involved, since `T` has nothing to do with it at all.

Comment: @jcalz I was able to find a solution with others' help, but yes I think your proposal is something along the same lines. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved by moving the generic to the inner function

```
export type Context = any;
export type Handler<T> = (ctx: Context) => Promise<T>;
export type Middleware = <T = unknown>(ctx: Context, handler: Handler<T>) => Promise<T>;

export const compose = <T>(...middlewares: Middleware[]): Middleware => {
  return async function compositeMiddleware<U>(ctx: Context, handler) {
    // ...
  };
}
```